# Angular UI Popover load custom template

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular UI Bootstrap popover . Rather than giving the text i want to load the popover content from Div or a html template. here is the sample directive i am using

```
app.directive('customPopover', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<span>{{label}}</span>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
        $(el).popover({
            trigger: 'click',
            html: true,
            content: attrs.popoverHtml,
            placement: attrs.popoverPlacement
        });
    }
};
```

});

```
<button popover-placement="bottom" **popover**="On the Bottom!" class="btn btn-default">Bottom</button>
```

How can i get custom text either from a Div or from any HTML template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can directly use `popover-template="your-template.html"` along with the other attribs of the button, because you are already using angular bootstrap version, that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work. I'm using the latest version of bootstrap ui. What version should I be on?

Comment: @ChesterRivas I'm trying to solve the similar problem. Here some working example (but it is not the newest version of bootstrap ui). http://plnkr.co/edit/ddBU1wme46qOKqVPXewo?p=preview